# jQuery Mobile proper way to initialize a listview

Tags: jquery-mobile

Here is my problem. I have a few hard coded pseudo pages in my index. Some filled with content, some empty which will be filled on user interaction only by ajax. This ajax content contains html lists. When they load they don't have the nice jquery mobile look so I have to call a .listview() method so the jqm framework parse it on my ajax callback. That is where I often get this JS error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'jQuery162027575719612650573' of undefined

The number is never the same...

I wonder if I use the proper way to parse a listview after the page loads the ajax content. the error seems to be triggered when there is slight lag for the loading and the complete event is triggered too soon and my listview is not yet in the DOM at that moment, just a guess. what is the recommended way to initialize a listview after an ajax call?

It is very unfortunate because when the js error occurs it seems to freeze any further js execution...

so here is my empty pseudo page:

```
<div data-role="page" id="playlist" data-add-back-btn="true">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1><g:message code="pd.playlist" /></h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content"></div>
</div>
```

right under it there is a script tag with the bind an ajax call on pageshow to activate the listview

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#playlist').bind('pageshow', function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "updatePlaylistTemplate.gsp",
        error:function(x,e){handleAjaxError(x,e);},
        beforeSend:function(){$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();},
        complete:function(){
            $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
            $('[data-role="listview"]').listview(); //re-active all listview
        },
        success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
            $('#playlist').find('[data-role="content"]').html(data);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

The updatePlaylistTemplate return this (extract):

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-split-theme="d"> 
    <li data-icon="delete"> 
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="loadGet('urlToRemoveProdiver',$('#playlist'),doOnCallBack);">Provider: Bell</a> 
    </li> 
    <li data-icon="delete"> 
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="loadGet('urlToRemoveChannel',$('#playlist'),doOnCallBack);">Rock - Classic Rock</a> 
    </li> 
    <li data-icon="refresh" data-theme="e"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="loadGet('urlToReloadPlaylist',$('#playlist'),doOnCallBack)">Refresh list</a></li> 
    <li data-role="list-divider">Next song</li> 
    <li> 
        <a href="urlToViewSongInfo"> 
            <img src="images/song.gif" /> 
            <h3>Albert Flasher</h3> 
            <p>The Guess Who</p> 
            <p class="ui-li-aside">Next</p> 
        </a> 
    </li> 
    <li data-role="list-divider">Now playing</li> 
    <li> 
        <a href="urlToviewSongInfo"> 
            <img src="images/song.gif" /> 
            <h3>Crime of the Century</h3> 
            <p>Supertramp</p> 
            <p class="ui-li-aside">14h49</p> 
        </a> 
    </li> 
    <li data-role="list-divider">Previous songs</li> 
    <li> 
        <a href="urlToViewSongInfo"> 
            <img src="images/song.gif"" /> 
            <h3>Desperado</h3> 
            <p>Alice Cooper</p> 
            <p class="ui-li-aside">14h45</p> 
        </a> 
    </li>
[...]
</ul>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What version of jQuery Mobile are you using? In the latest beta (1.0b2) you can trigger the `create` event on a dom element to have the framework initialize it:

> New “create” event: Easily enhance all widgets at once
>
> While the page plugin no longer calls each plugin specifically, it
>   does dispatch a “pagecreate” event, which most widgets use to
>   auto-initialize themselves. As long as a widget plugin script is
>   referenced, it will automatically enhance any instances of the widgets
>   it finds on the page, just like before. For example, if the selectmenu
>   plugin is loaded, it will enhance any selects it finds within a newly
>   created page.
>
> This structure now allows us to add a new create event that can be
>   triggered on any element, saving you the task of manually initializing
>   each plugin contained in that element. Until now, if a developer
>   loaded in content via Ajax or dynamically generated markup, they
>   needed to manually initialize all contained plugins (listview button,
>   select, etc.) to enhance the widgets in the markup.
>
> Now, our handy create event will initialize all the necessary plugins
>   within that markup, just like how the page creation enhancement
>   process works. If you were to use Ajax to load in a block of HTML
>   markup (say a login form), you can trigger create to automatically
>   transform all the widgets it contains (inputs and buttons in this
>   case) into the enhanced versions. The code for this scenario would be:
>
> $( ...new markup that contains widgets... ).appendTo( ".ui-page"
>   ).trigger( "create" );
>
> Create vs. refresh: An important distinction
>
> Note that there is an important difference between the create event
>   and refresh method that some widgets have. The create event is suited
>   for enhancing raw markup that contains one or more widgets. The
>   refresh method that some widgets have should be used on existing
>   (already enhanced) widgets that have been manipulated programmatically
>   and need the UI be updated to match.
>
> For example, if you had a page where you dynamically appended a new
>   unordered list with data-role=listview attribute after page creation,
>   triggering create on a parent element of that list would transform it
>   into a listview styled widget. If more list items were then
>   programmatically added, calling the listview’s refresh method would
>   update just those new list items to the enhanced state and leave the
>   existing list items untouched.

Link: http://jquerymobile.com/blog/

You can also copy the output that jQuery Mobile creates and use that structure rather than using `<li>` tags and depending on jQM to inititialize it:

```
<li data-role="list-divider" class="ui-li ui-li-divider ui-btn ui-bar-a ui-btn-up-undefined" role="heading"><span>List Divider</span></li>
<li data-theme="b" class="ui-li ui-li-static ui-body-b">Regular LI</li>
```

Comment: Yes that seems to fix the problem when I call the trigger method with create event on a specific id `code $("#playlist").trigger( "create" ); ` Thanks for the suggestion. I was looking for something more flexible, but that will do for the moment. I tried to be more general with my selector but everything I tried didn't work. It had to be on a specific id...