# JQuery Mobile UL List Still Not Working fro Dynamic List

Tags: javascript, listview, jquery-mobile

Has anyone come up with any solution to the JQuery Mobile UL List View?

I'm currently using JQuery Mobile 1.1.2 Alpha, and the bug I am referring to is an old one:

[jQuery Mobile proper way to initialize a listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7288199/jquery-mobile-proper-way-to-initialize-a-listview)

My list view looks like this:

```
<ul data-role="listview" id="store-info">
        <li>My First Store</li>
        <li>48 Big Oak Lane </li>
        <li>Stamford</li>
        <li>CT</li>
        <li>06903</li>
</ul>
```

I have tried to use:

```
$( "#store-info" ).listview();
```

and also this:

```
$('#stores_main_view').trigger('create');
```

on the following

```
<div data-role="content" id="stores_main_view" class="content ui-content" role="main">
<ul data-role="listview" class="ui-listview">
        <li>
    <form class="product-form">
        <ul data-role="listview" id="store-info">
        <li>My First Store</li>
        <li>48 Big Oak Lane </li>
        <li>Stamford</li>
        <li>CT</li>
        <li>06903</li>
</ul>

    </form>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Both yield the same error when trying to create a list dynamically:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'jQuery1710409190776059404' of undefined
```

Is there any good solution to this problem yet?

Comment: Did you try `$('#store-info').listview( "refresh" );`  Didn't work for me unless i had the refresh in there. What exists in the DOM and what is programmatically inserted?

Comment: I get this: Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on listview prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'

Comment: So that means your <ul> doesn't exist in the DOM until you programmatically insert it? I had a similar problem and my solution was to place the empty <ul data-role="listview" id="store-info"></ul> into my HTML, and then insert just the <li> elements programmatically. That way you can use refresh.

Comment: I've tried that also with this: http://pastebin.com/7S5YfiXR . This is an html string which gets appeneded to the body using $('body').append(html); and then trigger is used $('#product_browse').trigger('create');.....still products undefined error.

Comment: Can you please isolate your code and make an example using jsbin. That includes the javascript that generates the list.

Comment: I fixed by removing this line and replacing it with: //parentId = parentUrl || parentPage[ 0 ][ $.expando ],
   parentId = parentUrl,

Comment: Not sure of the side effect yet but everything seems to be working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The jQuery mobile code (in the method `_createSubPages`, exactly the one you quoted in the comment) is expecting created controls to be in a `.ui-page`.

Simply adding the class on the page where the control resides before calling `trigger('create')` fixed the problem for me.

```
$('#page-id').addClass('ui-page')
```

It also works if you do a

```
$.mobile.loadPage('#page-id')
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Glad to be of help. The bug I filed was closed since jQuery mobile doesn't support this scenario at this moment. I did figure out something in this logic though: any time you'd like to `.trigger('create')` you're probably about to show the page. `.trigger('create')` will make a difference if the page has *already been loaded before*. So in fact, you can either check for the `ui-page` class on the page before you call `.trigger('create')`, or simply call `trigger('create')` right after the `$.mobile.changePage()` that probably follows right after.

Comment: Hmmmmmm, I have to yell foul for a framework claiming it does not support a certain scenario, especially for one as simple as this.

Comment: It worked for me. My scenario was: 1) the page and its widgets are created using a template and some AJAX data, 2) jQM is asked for a refresh of all the page widgets with .trigger('create'), 3) the page is shown.

As at first run the page hasn't yet got the 'ui-page' class, my code failed with TypeError error. Adding the class before triggering the event worked. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#nav-panel").load("nav-panel.html", function () {
    $(this).trigger("create");
});
```